# How to use Azure Key Vault secrets in react App?

Tags: reactjs, azure-keyvault, defaultazurecredential

I tried to read the Azure Key Vault in React App using DefaultAzureCredentials, but is not working.

Tried every other way but no luck.I heard we cannot read KV Secrets in Client Side.
Can anyone help on how to read this secrets.

I tried to Get the secrets from KV using

Comment: Can you share your code in the question?

Comment: You should explain what is wrong with the current approach and create a minimal reproducible example right within your question.

Comment: @Shaik Moulali Can you check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-node-latest) to retrieve secret with DefaultAzureCredentials.

Answer (score 1):

*I tried the frontend with React JS and backend with JavaScript to retrieve Azure Key Vault secret using DefaultCredentials.*

**Code :**

***backend/server.js :***

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');
const { SecretClient } = require('@azure/keyvault-secrets');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const vaultUrl = 'https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net';
const secretName = '<secret_name>';

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors()); 
app.get('/api/secret', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const client = new SecretClient(vaultUrl, credential);
    const secret = await client.getSecret(secretName);

    res.json({ value: secret.value });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving secret:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error retrieving secret');
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

***package.json :***

```json
"dependencies": {
        "@azure/identity": "^4.0.1",
        "@azure/keyvault-secrets": "^4.8.0",
        "axios": "^0.24.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.2"
    }
```

**frontend :**

***src/components/SecretReader.js :***

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const SecretReader = () => {
  const [secretValue, setSecretValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSecret = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/secret');
        setSecretValue(response.data.value);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to retrieve secret:', error.message);
      }
    };

    getSecret();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Secret Value</h2>
      <p>{secretValue}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SecretReader;
```

***src/App.js :***

```js
import React from 'react';
import SecretReader from './components/SecretReader';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>My Azure Key Vault Secret Reader</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <SecretReader />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I provided access to my app, allowing it to retrieve the secret from the Azure Key Vault, as shown below:

[image]

**Output :**

The backend code started running on port 3000 as shown below.

[image]

I retrieved the secret from the Azure Key Vault as shown below.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/secret
```

```json
{
    "value": "Hi Kamali"
}
```

[image]

Then, I started my frontend React.js code on port 3001 as shown below.

[image]

I successfully retrieved the secret from the Azure Key Vault as shown below.

```
http://localhost:3001/
```

```
My Azure Key Vault Secret Reader
Secret Value
Hi Kamali
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Kamali, Thanks for the answer.

But here you called an API to get the Secrets. In my scenario I want that to get directly in the frontend react. 

Even If I follow your approach how and where should I mention the API url ? 
My approach for KV is to not store any configs inside my projects except KV Name. 
In the approach you suggested, I believe I have to store api end point.

Comment: @ShaikMoulali If possible, can you share your react code in the question?